# Using verilog to generate a ripple-carry-adder with all output X

Tags: verilog

I am a beginner and I wanted to write a ripple-carry-adder using the generate block. So I write the following module:

```
module ripple_carry_adder(ia, ib,  ci,  so,  co);

parameter N = 32;
input[N-1:0] ia;
input[N-1:0] ib;
input ci;
output[N-1:0] so;
output co;

wire [N:0] carry;
assign carry[0] = ci;

genvar j;
generate for(j = 0; j < N; j = j + 1) 
begin:r_loop
    wire t1, t2, t3;
    xor g1(t1, ia[i], ib[j]);
    xor g2(so[j], t1, carry[j]);
    and g3(t2, ia[i], ib[j]);
    and g4(t3, t1, carry[j]);
    or g5(carry[j+1], t2, t3);
end
endgenerate

assign co = carry[N];
endmodule
```

And the testbench module:

```
`include "ripple_carry_adder.v"
`timescale 1ns/1ps
module ripple_carry_adder_tb;

parameter N = 32;

reg clk;
reg[N-1:0] a, b;
wire[N-1:0] sum;
reg cin;
wire cout;

ripple_carry_adder rca(.ia(a), .ib(b), .ci(cin), .so(sum), .co(cout));
initial begin
    #10;
    a = 0;
    b = 0;
    cin = 0;
    clk = 0;
    #10;
end

always @(posedge clk)
begin
    #50;
    #1 a <= $random() % 1000000;
    #1 b <= $random() % 1000000;
end

always @(a or b)
    #5 $display("%d + %d = %d", a, b, sum);

always #5 clk = ~clk;

endmodule
```

But I got the result with all bits unknown:
[result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eo2u5.png)

I have spent 1 hour in vain trying to find the mistake. Can you help me?

Comment: The `i` in `ia[i]` is undefined. Undefined variables infer a single bit wire. Perhaps you meant `j`?

Comment: But it's very strange that this compiler doesn't even suggest a warning :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in my comment, the `i` in `ia[i]` is undefined. Changing it to `j` should get the desired functionality.

Verilog will treat any undeclared variable as a single bit wire, it is considered normal benavior and you will rarely get warnings. Some simulators have options to flag undeclared variables. There is a univeral option as well that was added in IEEE Std 1364-2001 (aka Verilog-2001). You can override the default net type with the `` `define_nettype `` macro. By setting it to `none` all nets after the macro declaration must be explicitly declared. You can get more details on default_nettype by reading IEEE Std 1364-2001 § 19.2 *`default_nettype* or [IEEE Std 1800-2012](https://standards.ieee.org/findstds/standard/1800-2012.html) § 22.8 *`default_nettype*

Comment: I add "`default_nettype none" at the begining of the source code and it works. Sadly, in this case , I have to add some extra "wire"s. I can't have my cake and eat it :(

Comment: You can put `` `default_nettype wire `` in the header of other files to restore the default. Just do not go crazy putting the macro everywhere; it makes it a nightmare to debug anything.